# All edits rejected on a post which contains chinese characters

Tags: bug

I tried to edit [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32509699/672) by formatting code and tweaking some unclear phrasing.

No matter what edit I tried, it told me that [whatever i typed] was not allowed.

Screenshots follow.

**Before any edits:**
[image: Before any edits]

**First attempted edit:**
[image]

**Second attempted edit:**
[image]

**Third attempt:**
[image]

Comment: Same problem when editing the question.

Comment: From the linked meta-posts it appears that this is a spam prevention measure. If that's necessary then it's fine with me but I still have two problems with it. 1) The same rule should be applied when posting the question as editing. In this case it appears the user was able to post the Chinese characters in an apparent violation of the rule. 2) The error message should clearly indicate why the edit is being rejected to avoid confusion

Comment: @joseph I get the same rules apply, but the question was asked before the filter was put in place